# Waiting for async operation completion in LevelDB C++ API

Tags: c++, leveldb

LevelDB allows to write in 2 modes: synchronously and asynchronously. The second mode is a default mode and you can set in Options struct:

```
 struct WriteOptions {
  // If true, the write will be flushed from the operating system
  // buffer cache (by calling WritableFile::Sync()) before the write
  // is considered complete.  If this flag is true, writes will be
  // slower.
  //
  // If this flag is false, and the machine crashes, some recent
  // writes may be lost.  Note that if it is just the process that
  // crashes (i.e., the machine does not reboot), no writes will be
  // lost even if sync==false.
  //
  // In other words, a DB write with sync==false has similar
  // crash semantics as the "write()" system call.  A DB write
  // with sync==true has similar crash semantics to a "write()"
  // system call followed by "fsync()".
  //
  // Default: false
  bool sync;

  WriteOptions()
      : sync(false) {
  }
};
```

I can write a single value, I can write a collection of updates (using a WriteBatch) but my question is: can I be somehow notified that all write operations are completed? I'm interested in C++ API, because for some other languages there are callbacks in this case. And I'm not interested in synchronous write, I just want to be notified that async operation is completed.

Comment: The problem is LevelDB does not know when an asynchronously write has completed. In async mode it does not call any of the various "flush" APIs it is therefore up to the OS file-system cache, network layer (if used), HDD cache to complete the write.  This is not callback related with LevelDB queueing the writes and being able to call you back, it is purely not calling "flush". See: https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/index.md#synchronous-writes

Comment: I checked the source code and thought so but still hoped there was a little chance to determine it :) Thanks a lot!